# WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "cameracalibrate"

Tags: python, camera-calibration, gstreamer-1.0, python-gstreamer

I am trying to run the following pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src ! videoconvert ! cameracalibrate ! cameraundistort ! autovideosink
```

The First part of my question is:

As I read in the documentation `cameracalibrate` and `cameraundistort` are elements that belong to opencv plugin and which we can use directly to create our own pipelines. Could someone please tell me if what I understood is right or not.

The second part is:

I am getting this error:

> WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "cameracalibrate"

I had already installed the `gst-plugins-bad`

I am beginner in Gstreamer, could someone help me please and tell me what is behind this error.

Comment: You should add which environment (OS/distribution) you are using and how you installed `gst-plugins-bad`, since that will make a difference in the end

Comment: @nielsdg thank you for your reply. I have windows10 , and i am working with Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). The command that i used to istall `gst-plugins-bad` is `sudo apt install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad `. Please what difference it will make that you were talking about. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the opencv-related plugins are part of "gst-plugins-bad", Debian (which you indicated you are using) [packages them separately](https://packages.debian.org/buster/gstreamer1.0-opencv). That way, people who don't want/need the OpenCV based plugins don't have to, along with all the (quite heavy) dependency tree that comes together with it.

So to solve your issue, you should be able to just use `sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-opencv`

Comment: I understand now the issue. Thank you for your explanation , it was clear and helpful.